# How to collect the information from the HTML using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-science

I am trying to scrape information from a HTML and create a dataset by taking the information from it.
I need to get info in "items" in the html like title,subtitle, authors,desc etc..,

```
import tempfile
import urllib.request
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 500)
import time
import requests
import random
from urllib.parse import quote 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

book_info = []
error_list = []
not_found = []
for title in unique_title[1:5]:
    try:
        page = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q="+quote(title))
        soup = bs(page.content,'lxml')
        if "items" in soup:
            volume_info = data["items"][0] 
            authors = volume_info["volumeInfo"]["authors"] if "authors" in volume_info["volumeInfo"] else  np.nan
            category = volume_info["volumeInfo"]["categories"] if "categories" in volume_info["volumeInfo"] else  np.nan
            pages = volume_info["volumeInfo"]["pageCount"] if "pageCount" in volume_info["volumeInfo"] else  np.nan
            publication_date = volume_info["volumeInfo"]["publishedDate"] if "publishedDate" in volume_info["volumeInfo"] else np.nan
                
            book_info.append({"google_id": volume_info['id'],
            "title": volume_info["volumeInfo"]["title"],
            "author": authors, 
            "publication_date": publication_date,
            "category": category,
            "pages": pages})
        else: 
            not_found.append(title)
    except Exception as e:
        error_list.append(e)
    time.sleep(np.random.random())
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMNsZ.png)

I am not familiar on how to access the information in soup. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The content of `<p>` is json string, so you can convert it to dict with [json.loads()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads).

After getting the dict, you can loop through the value of `items` and get information you want from it as following:

```py
for title in ['Bacterial Pathogenesis']:
    try:
        page = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q="+quote(title))
        soup = bs(page.content,'lxml')

        jsonData = json.loads(soup.find('p').get_text())

        for item in jsonData['items']:
            volume_info = item['volumeInfo']
            authors = volume_info.get('authors', np.nan)
```

Comment: when I executed the above code though it was looping more than necessary times and storing the same information multiple times.

Comment: @Raven I have no idea what you are going through. Because it depends on how you get items from `jsonData`. You can `print(type(jsonData))` to make sure it is dict type. In the above code, I just take book `Bacterial Pathogenesis` as an example. You may need to replace it with the books you want to process.